# How to prove that {$X \in M : det (AX)=0$} is not a subspace of M?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $M$ be a vector space of all $3\times 3$ real matrices and let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&1\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}.$$

I am struck on the following problem: Show that  $\{X\in M:\text{det}(AX)=0\}$ is not a subspace of M.

Can you please let me know why it can't be a subspace of M? What would be the contradiction?

Comment: Try adding $\begin {pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end {pmatrix}$ and $\begin {pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end {pmatrix}.$